# como puedo interpretar esto TypeError: select.appendChild is not a function?

Tags: javascript, html

estoy tratando que un objeto  se agrege al envoltorio , cada vez que se seleccione la opcion +, pero no pasa y al entrar al debugger se detiene en el appendChild de la funcion addAnaquel, diciendo, TypeError: select.appendChild is not a function, ademas alguna sugerencia para hacer el numero dentro del tag  recien creado dianmico, es decir que sume +1 de acuerdo al numero del tag <option anterior

```
  <body>
    <form class="databox" action="index.html" method="post">
      <label for="">Numero de pieza: </label><input type="number" name="" class="pieza" id="pie" value="">
        <label for="">Descripcion: </label><input type="text" class="descripcion" name="" value="">
      <label for="">Implemento/Tractor: </label><input type="text" class="type" name="" value="">
      <label for="">Precio: </label><input type="text" name="" value="" class="price">
      <label for="">Cantidad: </label><input type="text" name="" value="" class="cantidad">
      <label for="">Anaquel: </label><select class="select" name="anaquel">
        <option value="">1</option>
        <option id="anamas" value="">+</option>

      </select>
      <label for="">Repisa: </label><select class="seleccion" name="">
        <option value="">1</option>
        <option id="+2" value="">+</option>
      </select>
      <label for="">Poveedor: </label><input type="text" name="" value="">
      <label for="">foto: </label><input type="file" name="" value="">
      <button type="button" name="button" onclick="escribir()">Capturar</button>
    </form>
    <div id="repisa"></div>



    <script>

      
    
      /*     var descripcion = document.getElementsByClassName("descripcion").value
          var tipo = document.getElementsByClassName("type").value
          var precio = document.getElementsByClassName("price").value
          var quantity = document.getElementsByClassName("cantidad").value
          var anaquel = document.getElementsByClassName("anaquel").value
     
     
          
         let array = [pieza, descripcion, tipo, precio, quantity, anaquel] */
          
     
         function escribir() {
             // var pieza = document.getElementsByClassName("pieza").value;
             var pieza =  document.querySelector(".pieza").value;
           console.log(pieza)
          }
    
     let newoption = document.createElement("option") 
     var id = document.querySelector(".id")
     var masanaquel = document.getElementById("anamas")
     var select = document.getElementsByClassName("select")
     

         
         
     function addAnaquel() {
     select.appendChild(newoption).innerHtml= "2";
     }

  
     masanaquel.addEventListener("click", addAnaquel)
     
     
         </script>
  </body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Este error se debe a que estás tratando de ejecutar una función en un array.

La función getElementsByClassName() retorna un array, por lo que tendrás que especificar la posición del elemento antes de invocar la función

```
const select = document.getElementsByClassName("select")[0];
```

Esto hará que la constante `select` apunte al primer elemento con la clase select.

Puedes ver todos los elementos con
`console.log(document.getElementsByClassName("select"))`

Además, puedes usar selectores de CSS con querySelector.

`console.log(document.querySelector(".select"))`

Ten en cuenta que esto solo retornará el primer elemento con el selector, si quieres obtener todos los elementos en un array puedes usar querySelectorAll

`console.log(document.querySelectorAll(".select"))`

Answer (score 1):

Tienes estas líneas de código:

```
var select = document.getElementsByClassName("select")

function addAnaquel() {
 select.appendChild(newoption).innerHtml= "2";
}
```

Si miras bien el nombre del método usado, getElement**s**ByClassName, verás que está en plural: obtiene una colección de elementos, no un único elemento. En este caso será una colección con un único elemento, pero no deja de ser una colección (es decir, un array). por tanto, estás intentando llamar al método appendChild sobre un array, no sobre un elemento del DOM.

Por tanto puedes hacer:

```
var select = document.getElementsByClassName("select")[0];
```

o también:

```
const select = document.querySelector(".select");
```

que devuelve el primer elemento que cumpla con la condición.